# Using Watson AlchemyAPI on medical data

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, google-knowledge-graph

I'm trying to create a java app which uses information from a medical guideline to support the activity a doctor. The use case is that when the doctor asks a question or inputs a scenario to the system, it responds with the recommendations from the guideline that best fit the situation.
My idea is to extract name, relations and their knowledge graph from my document and use them to do some reasoning.
My questions are:

1. With AlchemyAPI can I extract entities using an external service? (Like a medical dictionary such as UMLS or MedlinePlus)
2. For those entities can I extract their knowledge graph and expand it with reasoning?
3. If it is not possible, would Knowledge Studio help me with this task? ( My document is a relatively small pdf, at maximum 100 pages)
4. This is a curiosity: Is there for Watson services some **detailed** Javadoc other than sdk doc, basic class tree, and tutorials? 
   Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at the [Natural Language Understanding (NLU)](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.mybluemix.net/) demo and see if the results based on some text from your use case are good enough. Otherwise, you will have to train a Knowledge Studio model and use it with NLU.
2. Watson doesn' have a knowledge graph that you can manipulate so you will have to develop this part. Once you get the entities from (1) you will have to create the knowledge graph.
3. Yes, see (1).
4. From your answer I assume you are using Java, in any case I think you need to first read the documentation for:

   - [Natural Language Understanding](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/natural-language-understanding/)
   - [Knowledge Graph](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/knowledge-studio/)
   - [Discovery](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/). I think that those 100 pages you need to analyze could be stored using this service which will help you to also run some other NLP tasks on those documents.